# How to properly swap the view *and* view model of a control?

Tags: c#, mvvm, avaloniaui

I'm using AvaloniaUI 11.0.0-preview7, MVVM Community Toolkit, and I'm trying to change the view and view model of a control that represents one of several things.

In this sample project, I bind the `DataContext` of a `ContentControl` to an `object` in the view model, then use `Xaml.Behaviors` to change the `Template` when a property (`Choice`) of the view model changes.

The following does the job:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="TransientState"/>
    
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Choice0Template">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding PropertyA}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="Choice1Template">
      <Button Content="{Binding PropertyB}"/>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <ia:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Choice}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="-1">
        <ia:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding #MyContentControl}" PropertyName="Template" Value="{StaticResource TransientState}"/>
      </ia:DataTriggerBehavior>
      <ia:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Choice}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="0">
        <ia:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding #MyContentControl}" PropertyName="Template" Value="{StaticResource Choice0Template}"/>
      </ia:DataTriggerBehavior>
      <ia:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding Choice}" ComparisonCondition="Equal" Value="1">
        <ia:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding #MyContentControl}" PropertyName="Template" Value="{StaticResource Choice1Template}"/>
      </ia:DataTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <ContentControl Name="MyContentControl" Template="{StaticResource TransientState}" DataContext="{Binding SubViewModel}"/>

    <Button Content="Change" Command="{Binding Change}"/>

  </StackPanel>
```

View model:

```
    public partial class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private int _choice = 0;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private object _subViewModel;

        private ViewModelA vma = new ViewModelA();
        private ViewModelB vmb = new ViewModelB();

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            _subViewModel = vma;
        }

        public void Change()
        {
            if (Choice == 0)
            {
                Choice = -1;
                SubViewModel = vmb;
                Choice = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Choice = -1;
                SubViewModel = vma;
                Choice = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    public class ViewModelA : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string PropertyA => "Property A";
    }

    public class ViewModelB : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string PropertyB => "Property B";
    }
```

However, I have the following two alternating errors when triggering the change, complaining that the properties of A aren't found on B and vice-versa:

> [Binding]Error in binding to 'Avalonia.Controls.TextBlock'.'Text': 'Could not find a matching property accessor for 'PropertyA' on 'VVMSwitching.ViewModels.ViewModelB''(TextBlock #7715150)

> [Binding]Error in binding to 'Avalonia.Controls.Button'.'Content': 'Could not find a matching property accessor for 'PropertyB' on 'VVMSwitching.ViewModels.ViewModelA''(Button #20908074)

Without the use of `TransientState`, I would understand: either the view or view model has to be updated before the other, which means at some point, the bindings are nowhere to be found.

This is why I first empty the view, then swap the view model, then switch to the new view. Yet, I keep getting these errors cluttering the output, as if the changes did not happen sequentially and synchronously.

Why ? What's the proper way to do this ?

PS: Should someone want to reproduce the issue, I have uploaded this sample project: https://github.com/JulienBernard3383279/AvaloniaPad/tree/master/VVMSwitching